Does my old film camera need a flash?
I’m a beginner and I just bought a Minolta Hi-matic F and a roll of Kodak Gold 200. I want to take photos of landscapes, but also portraits.
I’m wondering if I need a flash for this since it didn’t come with the camera.
Also, how do I know what ISO to set on the camera? I didn’t quite understand the guides online.

The ISO setting for film cameras doesn't affect the sensitivity or 'speed' of the film at all. Rather, it affects the calibration of the camera's light meter by telling it how sensitive the film that is loaded is.

The short answer: get a cheap digital camera (or just start with your phone) and learn with that first. Film is an expensive way to make mistakes.
The longer answer:

No, you don't need a flash, and definitely not for landscapes. Portraits in particular may be improved by off-camera flash.
In general, you set the ISO to whatever ISO your film is - i.e. 200 in your case. There are situations in which you might want to do something different, but now is not the time to worry about those.


+1 for the cheap camera, but one with settings that look more like those on a film camera.

Yes, get a cheap digital camera that allows one to directly control ISO, aperture, and exposure duration and is EXIF Info compliant so that every photo has what settings were used when the photo was taken embedded in the image's metadata. Digital allows a much faster learning curve without the per-shot expense of film.

I'm conflicted on whether to upvote or downvote this answer.  IMO, a digital camera isn't an ideal way to learn to use a film camera.  That may be because I learned to shoot film decades before digital existed, but I think it's more because digital lets you not think about what you're doing, because mistakes cost nothing.

@ZeissIkon Mistakes will still cost you once you switch over to film.  But your knowledge gain will let you get over the worst of the mistake phase quite a bit cheaper.  Also the learning loop for lab-developed color film is abysmally long these days since it takes weeks until you first see your results.  If you haven't kept notes, you won't even know what you did wrong (unless you have a databack that imprints the negatives with all the data, but those are not exactly a hallmark of cheap film cameras).

Yeah, and a Hi-Matic certainly doesn't have a databack.  I guess I'm just old -- I used to pay 49 cents (a week's allowance, more or less) for a roll of Verichrome Pan, and I could develop it in my bathroom.  Learned to develop and print at summer camp, age 9.  I'm also unfamiliar with any "cheap digital" cameras that offer full manual even for exposure...

I have a digital camera too! I’ll get started with that. Any tips on what i should focus on to begin with?

The Hi Matic F is an automatic exposure camera, it doesn't even display what settings are being used... there is no point in comparing/correlating the exposure to a digital camera, because you can't.

You do not need a flash, and you set the ASA to the film speed (ISO) rating on the canister; i.e. 200 for Kodak Gold 200.
The Hi Matic F is an auto exposure camera. If you find the exposures are off from what you expect/want then you could set the ASA to a different number to trick the camera into adjusting the exposure (higher ASA number for darker exposures).
You can also trick it into a longer/brighter exposure by covering the light sensor during the exposure in order to adjust it for a single frame (as opposed to for the entire roll with a fixed ASA offset).


I’m wondering if I need a flash for this since it didn’t come with the camera.

It depends on how much light you have to work with. Outdoors in the daytime, you do not need a flash. Indoors, without a tripod and depending on the ISO of your film, you might, but the Hi-Matic F has a reasonably fast 40mm f/1.7 lens on it. So with f/1.7 as the aperture if you use the equivalent of iso 800 (either with iso 800 film, or pushing 400 film by one stop) you could probably still get by without a flash or tripod and use handholdable shutter speeds (1/30s or faster). If you know how to hold your camera steady.
But doing something like pushing the film is something you have to do to an entire roll, not just an individual frame.
If you do choose to get a flash, learning how to expose with one can be trickier than just the "exposure triangle" iso/aperture/shutter speed thinking of exposure without a flash.  And the hotshoe on your camera only allows for manual flash; i.e., all the hotshoe can tell the flash to do is fire. You'd have to set the power level on the flash manually.  Also, with film, you won't see if you set things properly until after the film is developed, so keep notes with every frame on what you're doing.
Flash is very difficult to learn with film without wasting a lot of film along the way; it's much easier to learn with digital where you get instant feedback and can take as many images as you want without additional cost.

Also, how do I know what ISO to set on the camera?

Usually, whatever ISO the roll of film is is what you set on the camera. This will calibrate your light meter to adjust for the speed of the film. The higher the ISO number is, the larger the grains in the film's emulsion are, and the more light the film can grab more quickly. But the grainier your images will be.
See also:

What is the "exposure triangle"?
What do you recommend as a first step for hands-on learning about flash?
https://thedarkroom.com/pushing-and-pulling-film/

